# Run Angular4 from Visual Studio

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I have made one simple web application, where backend is done in .net core 2.0 and frontend is done in angular4.
[image]

If I want to start my application I should open cmd or power shell and write npm start. In that moment application is starting and browser is opening.

But if I want to run application with ctrl+f5 or just F5 from VS, on that moment browser is opening and application is not started, like that in background npm is not starting.
Here is code from package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "mypackage",
  "private": true,

  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.4.5",
    "@angular/router": "^4.4.5",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "systemjs": "^0.20.19",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^8.0.34",
    "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: I wrote an article for that specific purpose. Have a read here: https://medium.com/@faisalmuhammad/live-reloading-angular-application-with-asp-net-core-in-visual-studio-2017-957619f31008

Comment: If I deploy on IIS will work or need to manage different setup ? For me this solution doesn't works. Need to figure why...

Answer (score 0):

try this on your vscode

```
ctrl + `
```

and it will open the terminal tab at the bottom part and now run

```
npm start or npm run start
```

Comment: I dont want to use npm start. I want to run application from Visual Studio in debuging mode.